# controlling validation groups programmatically and only for the current transaction

Tags: validation, jpa, bean-validation

Is it possible to change which validation groups apply to say pre-update event for a short lived transaction?

i.e. tell jPA that when it commits the transaction it must apply a specific validation group to the pre-update event...

I know I can probably do this kind of validation manually - thing is I have the constraint setup and I have infrastructure to render constraint violation exceptions...

Answer (score 1):

Using the following properties:

- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist
- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update
- javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove

you can specify which groups should be targeted on validation of the related events. However, these are properties which are normally defined in *persistence.xml* or passed as properties at entity manager factory creation time. These are not properties you can change dynamically per transaction. AFAIK there is no way to do this programattically unless you trigger the validation yourself.

Comment: is it possible to trigger the validation yourself? I guess you could call the validator somehow...?